# Add Renderer to Vaadin Grid

Tags: java, html, vaadin

I migrating a Vaadin 8 project to Vaadin 14 and i try to show HTML in a grid column. 
I figured out, that i have to use a `TemplateRenderer`, but how can i use it?

Here is the code from Vaadin 8:

```
grid.addColumn(e -> {
    return ((Data) e).getValues()[index];
}).setCaption(myCaption).setRenderer(new HtmlRenderer());
```

In Vaadin 14 i did this:

```
gird.addColumn(e -> {
    return TemplateRenderer.<Data>of((String) e.getValues()[index])
}).setHeader(myCaption);
```

`e.getValues()[index]` includes HTML, for example: `<FONT SIZE = 4 COLOR = BLACK> &#9899;</FONT>`

In Vaadin 14 it always returns `com.vaadin.flow.data.renderer`.

Comment: Your code seems right. of takes the HTML String as template

Comment: But how can i show the html  in the cell correctly?

Comment: have a look at the docs https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/components/tutorial-flow-grid.html

Comment: The doc says that i have to call "withProperty" , but Data is only a list of Objects. And one object includes <FONT SIZE = 4 COLOR = BLACK> &#9899;</FONT>. So could i set a property?

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more what data is and what you want to display

Comment: If you need to inject property to inlined styles, there is an example here: https://github.com/TatuLund/devday-demo-flow/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vaadin/devday/demo/views/GridView.java#L166

Comment: In my Data Class is an Object Array that is called values. These values represents the data for my grid. In this case the values can only be null or <FONT SIZE = 4 COLOR = BLACK> &#9899;</FONT>.  So i just want to show the unicode sympbol  for &#9899

Answer (score 3):

Before we get to how to use a `TemplateRenderer` with Grid, I first need to point out that what you're trying to do is potentially dangerous because of the way it can lead to XSS vulnerabilities if the HTML strings that you want to show may be supplied by application users.

Using the `Html` component is indeed one potential solution to this problem, but it causes some overhead because there will be one component instance in memory for each row in the grid. There's also the same problem with potentially causing XSS vulnerabilities.

The first thing to notice with `TemplateRenderer` is that the renderer needs to be supplied directly as a parameter to `addColumn`. Wrapping it in a lambda will instead use that lambda as a value provider, which means that the `toString()` value of the renderer instance will be used with the default plain text renderer.

All rows should use the same renderer instance, configured with the same template string. The trick is that you can pass the data to show as a per-row property that the template will render for you. The last piece of the puzzle is that the template syntax tries to protect you against accidental XSS vulnerabilities, so you need to use a slightly contrived syntax to actually make it render the data as HTML.

Putting everything together, and also using `JSoup` to remove any dangerous stuff from your HTML strings, the working solution looks like this:

```
grid.addColumn(TemplateRenderer
        .<Data> of("<div inner-h-t-m-l='[[item.html]]'></div>")
        .withProperty("html", e -> {
            String unsafeHtml = e.getValues()[index];
            String safeHtml = Jsoup.clean(unsafeHtml, Whitelist.basic());
            return safeHtml;
        })).setHeader(myCaption);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution.
Instead of using the TemplateRenderer I used a ComponentRenderer.
The migration documentation recomented to use a TempleteRenderer or an ComponentRenderer instead of the htmlRenderer.

https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/migration/8-migration-example.html#step-4-product-grid

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
        grid.addColumn(new ComponentRenderer<>(e -> {
            String value = (String) e.getValues()[index];
            return new Html(value);
        })).setHeader(String.valueOf(col + 1));
```

Comment: Is the `index` a variable defined by you, or will it apply the row-index for it this way? I would assume the latter but have never seen this.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing your attempts with TemplateRenderer and the [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/v14/flow/components/tutorial-flow-grid.html#using-template-renderers), I would assume it will have to look like this:

```
grid.addColumn(e -> 
    TemplateRenderer.<Data>of("[[item.customValue]]")
        .withProperty("customValue", (String) e.getValues()[index])
).setHeader(myCaption);
```